# How to install node js without nodejs msi

Tags: node.js

I don't have admin permission to install the msi file in my window 7 machine.
How can i install and setup node.js on my windows machine without the msi? Is there any other way to setup this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [download](http://nodejs.org/download/) page provides a Windows Binary (EXE) version of Node.js. You can download that [here](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.25/node.exe).

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you. Could you please tick this as the answer, then that'll close the question :)

Answer (score -2):

If you don't have admin permission it's impossible, as far as I know, to install something like NodeJS.

Maybe you do have permission to install Virtualbox which is quicker to setup anyhow. Then it's just a matter of installing an Ubuntu or CentOS image.

Comment: I tried with node binary file. Now i am able to run the server. Thanks  James